# Как рассчитывать координаты узлов N-арного дерева в случае радиальной визуализации?

Tags: javascript, python, алгоритм, дерево, визуализация

Где можно почитать про то, как рассчитывать координаты узлов N-арного дерева в случае радиальной визуализации?

Пример такой визуализации на картинке (там скорее всего бинарное, мне бы N-арное)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Хз что такое радиальная визуализация, но я бы использовал поиск в ширину для вашей задачи

Comment: @tym32167 Ну, что в ширину - и так ясно) А как координаты-то найти?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Задаете сектор дуги окружности  в радианах и делите на количество узлов получаете шаг  между узлами в радианах. Координаты точек это параметрическое уравнение окружности  есть на википедии.

```
x=cos(angle_rad)*radius
y=sin(angle_rad)*radius
```